# Session based validation in ServiceStack

Tags: validation, servicestack

I have some validation logic, which is based a user's session. 
Сan I access the session from a class inherited from AbstractValidator?

Or is there another way to check RequestDTO based session?

For example I can use filters for that (and I can access the session via IRequest parameter req in overrided Execute method), but I don't know how to return the response from the class of the filter, bypassing the main method of the operation. If I will throw the Exception, the service will not work properly because RequestDTO declared outside of my project and it is not inherited from IReturn<> and does not contain a ResponseStatus field.

Thanks in advance for any help (and sorry for my English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your validator implements `IRequiresRequest` then it will injected with the current `IRequest` which you can use in your lambda expressions, e.g:

```
public class CustomValidator : AbstractValidator<Request>, IRequiresRequest 
{
    public IRequest Request { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but Request is not injected even if my validator implements IRequiresRequest. To register validators I use Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature()); container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AdminService).Assembly);

Comment: @VladimirShiyanov is this in the lambda expression? Because it's going to be null in the constructor.

Comment: Can you give a small example. I would be very grateful.

Comment: @VladimirShiyanov Update your question with what you're attempting to do that's not working (please also do this for all questions in future as otherwise it's very difficult to infer what you're trying to do)

Comment: Sorry, I carelessly read your answer. It's realy injected if I try access it from lambda expression. Thank you, very much.